# How to get a photo from Google Contacts API using JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-contacts-api

I could not able to get the photo from Google Contacts API. Here is the code I have used.

```
gapi.client.request({
method: 'GET',
path: '/m8/feeds/photos/media/default/1f27ce8913181e',
headers: {
        "Content-Type":"image/*",
        "GData-Version": "3.0",
        "if-match":"*",
        "data":token,
}
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
```

In the Content type I have tried both JSON, and XML. Also added the access_token in the URL above. So Please help me to get this image.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "could not"?  Did you get an error?  Explain what your problem is in more detail.

Comment: I got response from Google, in that the status is 404. There is no bytes for image.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Retrieving a contact's photo](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#contact_photo_management):

To retrieve a contact's photo, send an authorized GET request to the contact's photo link URL.

The URL is of the form:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}
```

With the appropriate values in place of userEmail and contactID.

```
Note: The special userEmail value default can be used to refer to the authenticated user.
The photo link can be retrieved from the contact entry returned by the API:

<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:gContact="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008"
    xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"
    gd:etag="{contactEtag}">
  <id>
    http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/base/{contactId}
  </id>
  ...
  <title>Full Name</title>
  <gd:name>
    <gd:fullName>Full Name</gd:fullName>
  </gd:name>
  <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo" type="image/*"
    href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/{userEmail}/{contactId}"
    gd:etag="{photoEtag}"/>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"
    href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full/{contactId}"/>
  ...
</entry>
```